# How to connect Socket.IO-Client to Sails.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I've spent quite a while trying to connect Socket.IO-Client to a server running on Sails.js framework. The client is basically a simple JavaScript application running with Node.js on Raspberry Pi.

The idea is that a simple device connects to a server, the server then registers the device and subscribes it for messages. The device receives a message from the server and performs some actions. I don't want the client to be dependant on any framework and, for that reason, I am trying to avoid using Sailsjs-socket.io-client. At the moment both server and the client are running on my local machine. Here is the code:

```js
// Server side. Sails.js. DevicesController.js

module.exports = {

  handshake: function (req, res) {
    if (!req.isSocket) return res.badRequest();
    Devices.create({}).exec(function (error, data) {
      Devices.subscribe(req.socket, data);
    });
    return res.ok();
  }

};


// Client side
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337/devices/handshake');

socket.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // Here I get 'Invalid namespace'
});
```

So, I get the error 'Invalid namespace' on the client side and, if I'm right, it means that the server doesn't have '/devices/handshake' open. However, on the server side if I list existing room ids (sails.sockets.rooms()), I can see that a new room is always created, when the client tries to connect to the server.

I tried to connect to '/devices/handshake' from a browser with the javascript below and apparently it worked. It obviously runs with Sailsjs-socket.io-client though.

```js
io.socket.get('/devices/handshake', function (data, jwres) {
  console.log(jwres);
});
io.socket.on('devices', function (data, jwres) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you're confusing a few concepts here: namely Socket.io namespaces, Socket.io paths and Sails routes.  You can learn a bit more about the first two by looking through the [Socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs).  The main thing to keep in mind as far as Sails is concerned is that it *only* listens for connections on the default `/` namespace; therefore, you should *always* connect client-side sockets with:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337');
```

Adding the `/devices/handshake` onto the end doesn't change the URL that the socket is attempting to connect to; it will always try to connect to `http://localhost:1337/socket.io`.  Instead, it means that it will try to register the socket with the `/devices/handshake` namespace, which Sails isn't providing.

On the other hand, when you call `io.socket.get('/devices/handshake')`, you're using the Sails socket client library to make a virtual request to that *route* in your app, just as if you'd used AJAX (e.g. `$.get('/devices/handshake')` in jQuery).  This is precisely why `sails.io.js` was created--it makes this sort of thing very easy!  It's also not really tying you down on the front-end; all `sails.io.js` does is provide some wrappers to make it easy to communicate with Sails backends via sockets.  Under the covers, `io.socket.get` is simply using the Socket.io-client `.emit()` method to send a `get` event to the server, with a payload describing the URL and parameters of the Sails action to run.  So, this:

```
io.socket.get('/devices/handshake', function(body, res){...})
```

is equivalent to connecting your own socket and doing this:

```
socket.emit('get', {url: '/devices/handshake'}, function(res){...})
```

The recommended approach for running logic for a socket when it first connects is to allow the socket to connect fully on the client, and then make a request from the client to the server (exactly what you're doing in your second code block).  To read more about the reasoning behind this, see [this note in the Sails 0.11.x migration guide](http://sailsjs.org/version-notes/0point10-to-0point11-migration-guide#?onconnect-lifecycle-callback).  That note also explains that if you *must* run the logic immediately upon server connection for some reason, you can do

```
sails.io.on('connect', function (newlyConnectedSocket){})
```

in your bootstrap function (`config/bootstrap.js`) .

Comment: Hey sgress454, I am struggling with a similar problem, but using the Python socketio client [See MY QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949932/how-to-connect-to-sails-socket-io-server-from-a-python-client-tried-sailssock). Would you have any further pointers?